# How to fix: mysqli_query(): load data local infile forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, file-upload

When trying to upload a csv file to the server, nothing is happening to the database. The errors log file shows a warning stating that: load data local infile is forbidden.

The same code runs perfectly in windows and ubuntu in localhost. But, on the server (ubunutu) things do not get working. We execute the same sql statement, as it is in php, on command line and it populates data on the database but when executing it in phpmyadmin it gives empty result.
We tried most of the solutions found on internet regarding this issue, but nothing is working: we set local-infile to true, we granted FILE to the user, we set permissions to 777, etc.

The sql statement is as follows:

```php
...
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path\to\file.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

**MySQL version:** 5.0.12

Comment: The filename would need to be surrounded by single quotes, not ticks, as well has having the full file path.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: The path should have regular quotes, not backticks. Backticks are reserved for SQL entities like columns or table names. You can also avoid double-backslashing by using single quotes for the string and double quotes within the string.

Comment: Actually, the filename is surrounded by single quotes. I just made this typo here. I work with MySQL 5.0.12

Answer (score -2):

**ANSWER:**

Step1 : Open your ***`php.ini`*** file.

Step2 : In ***`php.ini`*** find ***[Mysqli]*** or you can just search it.

Step3 : Just insert ***`mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`*** under ***`[Mysqli]`*** and save it.

Job's Done!!